# Update plot within observer loop in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a simulation in R that I want to visualize with shiny now. I have put the main part of the simulation into an *observe* block in order to be evaluated. During this evaluation process, i.e. for every iteration I want to plot the current status. The question is how do I achive this, since in my actual code the rendering of the plot is just executed after the main observer has been evaluated. Is there a way to, for instance, suspend the execution of the observe block and resume it after the plot has been updated?

Shouldn't there be some more functionality from shiny to address such a case, since I could imagine that I'm not the only one who would like to do something like this?!

It would be nice if you can help me with this :)

Below is some skeleton code for the server and ui.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("... Simulation"),

  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("epochs", 
                "Number of Epochs:", 
                min = 1,
                max = 100, 
                value = 10),
    verbatimTextOutput("curr.iter"),
    actionButton("actionB", "Action!")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

sinus <- data.frame()

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dummy <- reactiveValues(iter=0)

  obsMain <- observe({
    for (i in 1:input$epochs) {
      cat(i, " ")
      x <- seq(1:input$epochs)
      y <- sin(x)
      sinus <<- data.frame(x, y)
      dummy$iter <- i
      #
      # At this time I want distPlot & curr.iter to be evaluated/updated!
      #
      Sys.sleep(1)

    }

  }, suspended=TRUE)


  obsAction <- observe({ if(input$actionB > 0) obsMain$resume() })  # Helps to avoid initial evaluation of obsMain...

  output$curr.iter <- renderText({ as.numeric(dummy$iter) })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ if (dummy$iter > 1) plot(sinus, type="l") })

})
```

Answer (score 10):

I've been doing a little more thinking about this. I think the proper solution is to use `invalidateLater` to schedule work to occur in small chunks but allow other reactive dependencies to interrupt our long-running process to do things like updating graphs.

I put together a quick example at https://gist.github.com/trestletech/8608815 . You can run this with

```
runGist(8608815)
```

The basic premise is that we're doing some long-running iterative computing like what's done in your simulation, but we do it in smaller chunks to allow other reactives to run in between. My code is really simple to execute, so I can handle 100,000 iterations of my loop in ~1 second, which is about how long I'm willing to wait for my app to update interactively. I want to do 5 million iterations, so I schedule 50 chunks to occur.

Each time I run a chunk of 100,000 iterations, I'm updating a couple of reactive values that spawn some other updates that end up getting sent to my UI in a `renderText` (though a `renderPlot` like yours would work the exact same). If you run the app, you'll see that those reactives are updated in between each chunk I run before the next chunk gets scheduled to run.

There is a bit of overhead with this method, so your computation may slow down just a bit. But on my machine, 5 million iterations took 21 seconds when run all at once on the console, and took 23 seconds in this delayed-dispatch model. You could drive that down further by doing bigger chunks, of course.

Let me know what you think. I'm thinking it might make sense to wrap this up and either include pieces of it in Shiny or as an extension package.

Comment: Sorry for delay, i had plenty of other things to do... Nice job, I am currently inspecting your code :)

Comment: This solved my problem - wish these kind of more advanced reactivity flows were covered in the tutorials

Comment: Glad it helped. Coincidentally we launched http://shiny.rstudio.com/ a few minutes ago. You may find more help there, though I don't believe we yet have an article on this exact topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `Sys.sleep()` call in your code, I'm assuming you only want to run through one iteration per second. If that's the case, you could set a `reactiveTimer` that will evaluate code every second. Inside that timer, you'd run the code for the current iteration then bump up the `dummy$iter` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already saw the possibility of a reactiveTimer, but I just put the Sys.sleep() command in order to reserve some time for the plot to appear (in RStudio, for instance, I mostly have to do it the same way otherwise the plot does not show up). In my simulation the computational task will generate the neccessary delay. I'm just wondering whether there exists a possibility to trigger the rendering of the plot (whenever I want) and therefore can leave to simulation engine as it is, without the necessity to reconstruct the looping of the simulation.

Comment: You can render the plot whenever you want. The issue is that R is single-threaded. So if it's busy processing your simulation, then it's not evaluating other reactive dependencies. This isn't a well-thought-out part of Shiny just yet, but for now I think you'd need to schedule the "large" processing (simulation) to occur in small chunks (1 or just a few iterations) scheduled to occur every few milli/seconds -- the idea being that the CPU isn't 100% occupied by running the simulation, giving it time to evaluate other reactive contexts (like your plot).

Comment: I'd recommend trying it with a reactiveTimer scheduled 1/second. See that you can get the architecture working, then revise from there to either bring the timer down to a much smaller interval, or do more than one iteration each time the timer fires.