# Is there a way to trigger consecutive, timed events with single action button click in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an application that is meant to help students understand sampling. The application allows students to choose a sample size and then see how many 1's they get, given some probability. When sample size is small (i.e., 1), it often occurs that the same value (either a 0 or 1) is sampled multiple times in a row. However, if students click the action button to re-sample and get the same value as in their last random draw, I'm having trouble making it visually clear that the value has updated (i.e., that something happened, even though it gave the same result as before). Ideally, I would like the action button click to cause this field on the main panel to go blank for a fraction of a second and then display the new value.

I have tried using Sys.sleep to get the system to sleep for a second before proceeding, but this does not work. I can get it to (sort of) work by trying to print something else in the same output field before using Sys.sleep, but I feel like there must be an easier way.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Example"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("run", "Pick a number (0 or 1)")),
        mainPanel(
            h4("Your Number!"),
            textOutput("result")
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
        observeEvent(input$run, {
        x <- sample(c(0,1),size=1,prob=c(.5,.5),replace=T)
        ###Including these commented lines achieves what I want, 
        ###but doesn't seem very elegant:
        # output$result <- renderText({
        #     print("something")
        # })
        Sys.sleep(1)
        output$result <- renderText({
            paste("You got the number ",x)
        })
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282228/update-plot-within-observer-loop-in-shiny-application) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270540/force-shiny-to-render-plot-in-loop/47285598#47285598)